# Performance of storing a coordinate as an object vs two doubles in C#

Tags: c#, performance, profiling, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to optimize an algorithm that makes use of a list of coordinates.  We are following Domain Driven Design principles - `Coordinate` is currently defined as a class in a separate ValueObjects project which is used by the main project.  The `Coordinate` class consists of two `double`s (latitude and longitude) and some validation in the constructor to ensure valid coordinates when writing.

Using Visual Studio's profiling tools I have found that a large amount of my processing ends up in the get_Longitude and get_Latitude functions.  This might just be due the huge number of calls made.

Would be worth storing the coordinates as two doubles instead of an object that contained two doubles as properties?  Or would this just decrease readability with no performance improvement?

Comment: Have you considered using a struct instead of a class? This sounds like an entirely reasonable use for a value type...

Comment: We are following DDD principles - our `Coordinate` class (and `Distance`, `Speed`, etc.) are all in a separate ValueObjects project compiled to a separate DLL. Each class contains validation and conversion methods which is why we preferred classes over structs. Would retrieving doubles from a struct perform better than retrieving it from a class? If so, I could read the coordinates into structs before I run the algorithm.

Comment: "Each class contains validation and conversion methods which is why we preferred classes over structs." I don't see how that follows at all. `DateTime` has conversion and validation methods, for example... You shouldn't think about just one aspect (retrieval) - think about all aspects of value types vs reference types.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was under the impression that structs should not contain such methods but I'm convinced of your viewpoint after reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx. This article deals mainly with memory though.  For the purposes of this algorithm, processing speed is critical, more so than any other factor - including strictly following patterns.  Would it be faster to retrieve the doubles from a struct than from a class?

Comment: You should test that for yourself. Structs will have the benefit of locality of reference, but if you normally have lots of references to a few objects, you'll increase memory usage by having structs. Basically you should think carefully about *all* the implications, and then run tests to see what the impact is in your particular scenario.

Comment: The objects are distinct by the time I get to the algorithm, so I am using the memory anyway (besides, memory takes a back seat in this scenario).  Thanks, I will test to see if having structs (and thus locality of reference) gives a performance improvement, was just wondering if there is a general rule for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Coordinate` is a value object, it is immutable. Thus, using two `readonly public` fields would be completely acceptable (but read the rest).

Moreover using a struct you could further improve the computation performances (as Jon Skeet pointed out in the comments).

From a DDD perspective these are implementation details that are perfectly fine.

Moreover:

- for validation, I would use static **factory methods** in the `Coordinate` definition
- for computation, I would code a **closure of operations** right in the `Coordinate` definition (but avoiding operator overloading, if performance matters)

These two DDD patterns could prove well in your context.

Having factory methods (and proper semantics for the default value) in the struct, enable you to remove validation logic in the constructors, since invariants would be ensured by the factory methods themselves (actually you would not have any public constructor except the default one).

Moreover, supposing your `Coordinate`s form a [additive group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_group), the struct could expose an instance method `Coordinate Add(Coordinate other)`.
In the implementation you would not need any validation, but the computation (based on access of the `other`'s private fields) and the initialization since you know that your current instance is valid and so it is the argument.

Note that if you go far enough with **closure of operations** you won't need any public field or property.

Indeed, if you care about OOP design, instead of exposing any internal info (property or field, doesn't change much) you could expose a couple of methods like the following without violating encapsulation

```
    public void Eval(Action<double, double> action)
    {
        if(null == action)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        action(_lat, _long);
    }

    public T Eval<T>(Func<double, double, T> function)
    {
        if (null == function)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
        return function(_lat, _long);
    }
```

Furthermore, if you need such methods, but they don't belong to your ubiquitous language, you could hide them behind an explicit implementation of an **infrastructural** `interface`.